# Responsive Gallery: overlayed captions will not line up to edges of images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gallery, caption

I am putting together a simple responsive gallery using twitter-bootstrap.

I would like to have captions appear overlayed onto the images. They should be aligned to the bottom, right corners of each image.

I cannot get them to align, they exceed the edges of the images.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container">

<div class="row ">
  <ul>

        <li class="col-md-8 image">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/1llTChm.jpg" width="940px" height="627px" />
          <div class="desc">
            <h2>Caption text here</h2>
          </div>
        </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
    ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  }

img {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

div.desc{
    background-color: #000;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #fff;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0px;
}

.image {
  width:100%;
  padding:0px;
  }
```

You can see an example here although due to being embedded on jsfiddle it appears to be switching into small screen mode:

But you can still see how the captions exceed the image edges.

I would like the captions to line up with the image edges.

From what I can tell, the captions are aligning to the width of twitter-bootstraps .col-md-8 class. Which has padding to create the column gutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution for this to postion margin values

For this, Using negative(-) pixel in Margin-top to position

```
    <div class="container">

<div class="row ">
  <ul>

        <li class="col-md-8 image">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/1llTChm.jpg" width="940px" height="627px" />
          <div class="desc">
            <h2>Caption text here</h2>
          </div>
        </li>


      <li class="col-md-4 image">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/1llTChm.jpgg" width="940px" height="627px" />
        <div class="desc">
          <h2>Caption text here</h2>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="col-md-4 image">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/1llTChm.jpg" width="940px" height="627px" />
        <div class="desc">
          <h2>Caption text here</h2>
        </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <ul>
      <li class="col-md-4 image">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/1llTChm.jpg" width="940px" height="627px" />
        <div class="desc">
          <h2>Caption text here</h2>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="col-md-4 image">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/1llTChm.jpg" width="940px" height="627px" />
        <div class="desc">
          <h2>Caption text here</h2>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="col-md-4 image">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://i.imgur.com/1llTChm.jpg" width="940px" height="627px" />
        <div class="desc">
          <h2>Caption text here</h2>
        </div>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 }

img {
 padding-bottom: 20px;
} 
div.desc{
    background-color: #000;
 margin-top: -72px; /*This do the Trick*/
color: #fff;
opacity: 0.5;
width: 80%;
}
.image {
 width:100%;
 padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: Where do I need to apply a negative margin-top position? To which element? Oh I get it now, I can apply that to class .desc!